# Present screen based on 2 values

Tags: swift, swiftui, integer, screen

I have 2 Integers: Xcode and Ycode. These are bindings from previous screens.
Now what I want is to present a new view based on these integers.

The app is a small quiz. So the Xcode and Ycode are the score.
But I want to present a new view when you click on the button "Click me" based on the Xcode and Ycode.

For example:

```
Value X = between 8-15 and value Y = between 8-23 -> present screen1
Value X = between 8-15 and value Y = between 24-40 -> present screen2
Value X = between 16-23 and value Y = between 8-17 -> present screen3
And so on......

This is my Code:
      @Binding var Xcode: Int
        @Binding var Ycode: Int
        @State var ShowButton: Bool = false
        @State var ButtonYes: Bool = false
        @State var ButtonNo: Bool = false
        @State var ButtonSometimes: Bool = false

    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
        Image("Zebras")
            .resizable()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            
            
            VStack{
                Text("Wat ben ik?")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                Spacer()
                Text("Je heb alle vragen beantwoord. Nu is de vraag: Welk dier ben ik?")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                Spacer()
                
                Text("Your score:")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                
                HStack (spacing:0){
                    Text("X = ")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                    
                Text(String(Xcode))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                }
                HStack (spacing:0){
                                        
                    Text("Y = ")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                    
                Text(String(Ycode))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                }
                Spacer()
                
                
                
                Button("Click here!") {
                    
                    
                }
                    
                .frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .background(ButtonYes ? Color(red: 0.272, green: 0.471, blue: 0.262) : Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                Spacer()
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I create that?

Comment: Confused!!! Can you briefly explain?

Comment: You could use a `switch` statement, you could use `if-else` statements. Your question is lacking in information, how are you "presenting" a screen? I would suggest updating your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that includes a small example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: It was a small quiz, so the value Xcode and Ycode are scores. I want to present a new view based on those 2 scores. For example. Value Xcode is between 1-10 and Value Ycode is between 5-15 present view1. Value Xcode is between 10-20 and Value Ycode is between 10-15, present view2. And so on. Is that better or is it still a bit vague?

Comment: you can create customized function that accepts lower and upper limit of X-value and Y-value and returns the relevant screen to present

Comment: Thank you, Nayan Dave, can you give me an example? I'm rather new to coding so anything you can give me I can learn from.

Comment: You should try yourself and we can help u with the kinks this isn’t the place for free code. Research and trying are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContentView with 2 values: valueX and valueY. Then the ranges you need. Then a computed property to decide to which screen should navigate. The button is only created if the computed property doesn't return nil. And the destination of the navigation link has a switch which decides the screen to show and a label that is the button to be clicked.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MContentView: View {
    @State var valueX = 17
    @State var valueY = 15
    
    @State var isNextViewActive = false
    
    private let range8_15 = 8...15
    private let range16_23 = 16...23
    private let range8_23 = 8...23
    private let range24_40 = 24...40
    private let range8_17 = 8...17
    
    private var screenToPresent: Int? {
        if range8_15.contains(valueX) && range8_23.contains(valueY) {
            return 1
        } else if range8_15.contains(valueX) && range24_40.contains(valueY) {
            return 2
        } else if range16_23.contains(valueX) && range8_17.contains(valueY) {
            return 3
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if let screen = self.screenToPresent {
                NavigationLink(isActive: self.$isNextViewActive, destination: {
                    switch screen {
                    case 1:
                        MView1()
                    case 2:
                        MView2()
                    case 3:
                        MView3()
                    default:
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.isNextViewActive = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Click me!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("My View 1")
    }
}

struct MView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("My View 2")
    }
}

struct MView3: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("My View 3")
    }
}

struct MExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MContentView()
    }
}
```

Hope is what you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I was looking for! And thank you for taking the time to response to my question :)

Answer (score 2):

you could use this approach, using a tuple, a switch and some NavigationLinks:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var xy = (5.0,7.0) // <-- use a tuple
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            QuizView(xy: $xy)
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct QuizView: View {
    @Binding var xy: (Double, Double)
    
    // set of ranges of your scores for each screen
    let screen1X = 1.0..<4.0
    let screen1Y = 2.0..<4.0
    
    let screen2X = 3.0..<4.0
    let screen2Y = 4.0..<8.0
    
    let screen3X = 5.0..<9.0
    let screen3Y = 6.0..<8.0
    
    @State private var action: Int? = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                switch xy {
                case (screen1X,screen1Y): action = 1
                case (screen2X,screen2Y): action = 2
                case (screen3X,screen3Y): action = 3
                default:
                    print("---> default")
                }
            }) {
                Text("Click me")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("screen1X"), tag: 1, selection: $action) {EmptyView()}
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("screen2X"), tag: 2, selection: $action) {EmptyView()}
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("screen3X"), tag: 3, selection: $action) {EmptyView()}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question! This is also what I was looking for! I learned a lot from this answer, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could have hidden [navigation links](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) like these:

```
NavigationLink(destination: View1(), isActive: $condition1, label: { EmptyView() })
NavigationLink(destination: View2(), isActive: $condition2, label: { EmptyView() })
NavigationLink(destination: View3(), isActive: $condition3, label: { EmptyView() })
// note that having empty views for your links will keep them hidden on your layout
```

for each of your X and Y conditions.

So, when you check for X and Y values, you could verify them like this:

```
condition1 = Xcode >= 8 && Xcode <= 15 && Ycode >= 8 && Code <= 23
condition2 = Xcode >= 8 && Xcode <= 15 && Ycode >= 24 && Code <= 40
condition3 = Xcode >= 16 && Xcode <= 23 && Ycode >= 8 && Code <= 17
```

and that would activate the link you want and present the screen you need.